# Discrepance obtaining values not in inner join by difference

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have table A and table B. I know table B has 7848 rows (count(*)) and I want see which of those 7848 exist inside table A. As far as I know INNER JOIN returns the values that appear in BOTH tables A and B. So I inner joined them like this:

```
SELECT *
 FROM 
  TABLE1 AS A
 INNER JOIN 
  TABLE2 AS B
 ON A.field1 = B.field1
```

This query returns 1902 rows. Now, I want to find out which rows did NOT appear in table B so I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE FIELD1 NOT IN (field1*1902....);
```

By difference I think I should be getting a result of 5946 rows, since I found 1902 positive rows. What is weird is that this NOT IN statement returns 6175 rows and if I add them I get 8077 which is more than count(*) told me table B had.

What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join is a kind-of multiply. If you have multiple rows in table A with the same field1, then rows in B are counted multiple times.

Perhaps you want

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B B
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT field1 from TABLE_A A WHERE A.field1 = B.field1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT *
 FROM 
  TABLE1 AS A
 LEFT JOIN 
  TABLE2 AS B
 ON A.field1 = B.field1
 WHERE B.field1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query returns rows from table A that aren't on table B:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE field1 NOT IN (SELECT field1 FROM TABLE2)
```

You can also get rid of the IN condition for better performance:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 B WHERE B.field1 = A.field1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have some duplicated values in Table1 that are also present in Table2. Your first query will return those records multiple times.

You also need to be careful if you have null values: INNER JOIN and NOT IN won't return those values.